# Can someone provide an example of a collection of matrix that is an open set?

Tags: general-topology, matrices

I am totally confused what it means for a matrix to form an open set. Open set to me is either an interval **( , )** in $\mathbb{R}$ or some dotted circle in $\mathbb{C}$ (ok, the dotted circle being $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$)

Can someone provide an intuitive explanation why and how certain collection of matrices form open set?

Comment: A matrix is not an open set, any more than a number is an open set. Now, a *collection* of matrices is a different story...

Comment: thanks I edited the queston

Comment: Have you read the definition of an open set? It's not what you wrote.

Comment: The set of all matrices is a four-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. Hence, you can put the topology of $\Bbb R^4$ or $\Bbb C^4$ on it. You can even put a norm on it - namely $\|A\|={\rm tr}(AA^T)$, and this induces a metric (distance function) $d(A,B)=\|A-B\|$. You can then form open sets as unions of open balls with respect to this metric, and this will yield the Euclidean topology I just mentioned.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading, isn't a simple example 'the set of n x n matrices with determinants that fall within a given open interval'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, where $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with real entries, and $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is called the general linear group which consists of invertible matrices.

Consider the determinant of a matrix as a map;that is,

$$det:GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus \left \{0  \right \}$$

The map is continuous and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \left \{0  \right \}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.Hence $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is open in $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Similarly, $SO_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $O_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, where $O_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $SO_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ are called the orthogonal group and special orthogonal group respectively.
Again, consider the map
$$det:O_{n}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \left \{ \pm 1 \right \}$$
The inverse image of 1 by this map is $SO_{n}(\mathbb{R})$.Since the point 1 is open in $\left \{ \pm 1 \right \}$ we have that $SO_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $O_{n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Again, $SL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a closed subset of $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ since {1} is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry but why do you need the continuity condition?

Comment: @FemaleTank A continuous function is one in which preimages of open sets are continuous. Thus if $\det$ is continuous, the preimage of the open set $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, which is ${\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R)$, is open.

Comment: @FemaleTank Let $\Phi :X\rightarrow Y$ be a map between metric spaces $(X,d_{X})$ and $(Y,d_{Y})$.We have that $\Phi$ is continuous if and only if, for every open subset $V$ of $Y$, the inverse image $\Phi^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 3):

$GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ the linear group of invertible matrices is an open set in $\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R})$ the space of $n\times n$ matrices because it is the inverse image of $\Bbb{R}^*=\{x\in \Bbb{R},\,x\neq0\}$ which is open in $\Bbb{R}$, by a continuous (polynomial) function namely the determinant.

Comment: Are there some lower dimensional object that is analogous to your example?

Comment: $GL_1(\Bbb{R})$ is just non zero real numbers and is of dimension $1$, $GL_2(\Bbb{R})$ is of dimension $4$ ($2\times 2$ matrices) etc.